# Retrieve Data From Database Using ADODB in C#

Tags: c#

I am developing a project in C#.I am retrieving data from database to textbox.

In vb following code is used for retrieve data.

```
empcode.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(mRS("Accode").Value), "", mRS("Accode").Value)
```

And In C# I am using following code to retrieve data.

```
empcode.Text = mRS["Accode"] == System.DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : mRS["Accode"].ToString();
```

But in C# code it is giving following error in "mRS["Accode"]".

"Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression type 'Recordset'".

Where mRS is Recordset.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: What do you mean Recordset? What is the type for mRS?

Comment: Your C# version is probably very old, before 4.0.  It did not yet support default properties that are not indexers.  So you have to write mRs.Fields["name"].Value.  Try not to get stuck on 8+ year old versions of free software.

Comment: Hello, I am using visual studio 2015 and c# version is 6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB the expression `mRS("Accode")` is expanded to `mRS.Fieldset("Accode")` automatically. So you should write `mRS.Fieldset["Accode"]` in C#.

Answer (score 0):

```
mRs.Fields["name"].Value
```

worked for me.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?